# Project tree is lost in Intellij IDEA using git to synchronize

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am trying to use the integrated git in Intellij IDEA. On the first computer, everything is fine. Files are uploaded correctly.

However, when I try to pull the project on another computer, although all files are properly downloaded from GitHub, Intellij IDEA could not correctly recognize the project structure.

Only files in the root directory are recognized, the src folder and files in it disappeared.

I have two screenshots here:
[Project Structure inside Intellij IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KatfN.png)
[Actual Files on the disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VNZ6.png)

I am using Windows 10 on both computers, running the latest version of Intellij IDEA and git.exe. The project is hosted by GitHub.

Comment: are you using windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows....the go to your project root path and type this command

```
**git stash**
```

i am using Bitbucket and sourceTree on machine so sometimes i am getting the same situation and using this command i can able to get all the code.